# Sistema de reservas por horas

Tags: php, mysql, angular

estoy haciendo un sistema de reservas o citas como bien queráis llamarlo...

Os pongo en situación, yo puedo dar citas de dos formas distintas de 1:30 en 1:30 o puedo dar citas de 00:30 minutos por lo cual yo tengo un campo select en el que le digo oye que voy a asignar citas de 00:30 para el día que yo seleccione en otro campo que tengo tipo date, entonces el va a la base de datos y carga las citas que ya hay asignadas y ahora bien yo quiero que me muestre los tramos libres entre esas horas, como podría hacerlo?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La duda es como puedo saber que huecos están libres para asignar las citas de 01:30h y si no hay tiempo suficiente entre dos citas que estén ocupadas que no me muestre como libre ya que no podría asignarlo

Comment: buenas. Por favor, añade el codigo de lo que estas probando para ver si podemos echarte una mano de la mejor manera posible. Asi de pronto, podrias definir un array con todos los posibles tramos que tiene el dia, y luego recorrerlos en orden. Si coincide que alguno de ellos esta ocupado, lo dibujas en rojo. Sino, en verde.

Comment: Hola @Jakala el problema de eso, es que yo tengo 2 tramos para dar citas no siempre son iguales las citas unas duran 30 minutos y otras 1:30 minutos.

Comment: Entiendo. Por favor, añade tu codigo para que podamos ver que has conseguido hasta ahora. Si ese es tu caso, piensa que el tramo de 1:30min es en realidad 3 tramos de 30min... Quizas con eso puedas dividir de alguna manera mas optima tu listado de citas.